# Selenium - unable to locate element for static text

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find **TEST-335** from a modal whose HTML snippet is as under:

```
<p class="staticText" data-name="title"  data-reactid=".7.0.0.1">TEST-335</p>
```

I am using the below code-snippet:

```
By.cssSelector("div[id=" + name + "] input[data-name=title]");
```

But it throws error as below:

> "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[id=instViewFileServerModal]
>   input[data-name=title]"}"

-- Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is not confined to CSS, you can use xpath as below to fetch the text directly:

`By.xpath("//p[.='TEST-335']")`

This will fetch the `p` tag with exact innerHTML or inner text as `TEST-335`.

Comment: it works but had to use CSS. After further debugging, this seems to work modTitle = By.cssSelector("[data-name='title']"); thanks